Autocompletion tooltip when dev tool is opened
Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of this?

I mean that Devtools testing autocomplete tooltip.
What I tried to far:

in devtool -> settings -> source -> turn automplete off

click on the Manage Addresses at the bottom of the tooltip, and within the opened form turn it off.


It keeps coming back. The autocomplete attribute on that input field is off, maybe that's the reason.
Tried to find it in Chrome's dev tool documentation, but no luck.

Currently this "feature" is a experiment on Chromium. In theory, for disabling it you can go to:
devtool -> settings -> experiments -> toggle off "Autofill Panel"
But this setting is broken, so for now the only way I found is to open an instance of the browser passing a flag via command line:
windows: start chrome --restart --flag-switches-begin --disable-features=AutofillTestFormWithTestAddresses

mac: open -a "Google Chrome" --args --restart --flag-switches-begin --disable-features=AutofillTestFormWithTestAddresses

linux: google-chrome-stable --disable-features=AutofillTestFormWithTestAddresses 

On my case I'm using Brave, which is based on Chromium, and I have to run:
open -a Brave\ Browser  --args --disable-features=AutofillTestFormWithTestAddresses

You can read more on: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/329106326
I hope this helps
